# unix timestamp wrong time with rrdtools

Tags: linux, bash, rrdtool, time

I have problem with unix timestamp ( date +%s ). This command gives me a GMT time, however I am using CET, so the unix timestamp is in 1 hour late (and my rrdtool database too!). How I can change unix timestamp's to CET or add +1 hour?

With command "date" I get good time.
Update:

@ubuntu:~/tmp$ date +%s%Z
1295915413CET
@ubuntu:~/tmp$ cat /etc/timezone
Europe/Bratislava
@ubuntu:~/tmp$ date
Tue Jan 25 01:30:28 CET 2011
@ubuntu:~/tmp$ date +%s
1295915459
@ubuntu:~/tmp$ in normal time: Tue, 25 Jan 2011 00:30:13 GMT

Update2:

In online converters I can set the timezone, so maybe the numbers are equal for all timezone? Then the question is that, why rrdtools late a hour?

@ubuntu:~/tmp$ date -d @1295916112
Tue Jan 25 01:41:52 CET 2011

As we can see the timestamp is correct, only rrdtool is wrong. But why?

Comment: We don't delete questions that could be of benefit to someone else later. Please roll back your edit. Especially so people can see what the actual solution is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's odd. On my Ubuntu Linux system I get unix time in CET when I enter `date +%s`.

Could you show us the output of `date +%s%Z`? And could you `cat /etc/timezone`?

Comment: That's odd, `date %s` shows me a number of seconds without a time zone.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

That's what `%s` is supposed to do. From `man date`:

```
%s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```